# hyperref points wrong table with reset counter

Tags: tables, hyperref, cross-referencing, appendix

I have an issue with hyperref and reference to my tables listed in the appendix section. It seems for some tables there is confusion in listing the right table number.

For ex. Table (A8) is cited instead in text after using \ref as table (A.4) although it navigates to the right table in the appendix which is A8. This problem happens only with a number of tables, not all. I tried getting around it but nothing worked out. Could anyone please advise me on how to fix this? Thank you in advance!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{float}   
\usepackage{amsmath }
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
%%%\usepackage{lscape} % don't load both lscape and pdflscape
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\usepackage[paper=portrait,pagesize]{typearea}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{agsm}
\usepackage{longtable}
\newcommand{\etal}{\textit{et al.}}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{array}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\usepackage{booktabs}% http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs
\usepackage{vcell}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{calc}% http://ctan.org/pkg/calc
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
%%\usepackage{amsfonts}  % 'amsfonts' is loaded automatically by 'amssymb'
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\usepackage[misc]{ifsym}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\providecommand{\keywords}[1]{\textbf{\textit{Keywords}} #1}

\makeatletter

% Patch case where name and year are separated by aysep
\patchcmd{\NAT@citex}
  {\@citea\NAT@hyper@{%
     \NAT@nmfmt{\NAT@nm}%
     \hyper@natlinkbreak{\NAT@aysep\NAT@spacechar}{\@citeb\@extra@b@citeb}%
     \NAT@date}}
  {\@citea\NAT@nmfmt{\NAT@nm}%
   \NAT@aysep\NAT@spacechar\NAT@hyper@{\NAT@date}}{}{}

% Patch case where name and year are separated by opening bracket
\patchcmd{\NAT@citex}
  {\@citea\NAT@hyper@{%
     \NAT@nmfmt{\NAT@nm}%
     \hyper@natlinkbreak{\NAT@spacechar\NAT@@open\if*#1*\else#1\NAT@spacechar\fi}%
       {\@citeb\@extra@b@citeb}%
     \NAT@date}}
  {\@citea\NAT@nmfmt{\NAT@nm}%
   \NAT@spacechar\NAT@@open\if*#1*\else#1\NAT@spacechar\fi\NAT@hyper@{\NAT@date}}
  {}{}

\makeatother
\usepackage{hyperref} % it's a good idea to load this package _last_
\hypersetup{
    pdftoolbar=true,        % show Acrobat’s toolbar?
    pdfmenubar=true,        % show Acrobat’s menu?
    pdffitwindow=false,     % window fit to page when opened
    pdfstartview={FitH},    % fits the width of the page to the window
    pdftitle={title},    % title
    pdfauthor={Salvatore Mazzarino},     % author
    pdfsubject={Subject},   % subject of the document
    pdfcreator={Salvatore Mazzarino},   % creator of the document
    pdfproducer={Salvatore Mazzarino}, % producer of the document
    pdfkeywords={Green Networking} {Mobile Cloud} {Network Coding} {Energy}, % list of keywords
    pdfnewwindow=true,      % links in new window
    colorlinks=true,       % false: boxed links; true: colored links
    linkcolor=blue,          % color of internal links (change box color with linkbordercolor)
    citecolor=blue,        % color of links to bibliography
    filecolor=magenta,      % czolor of file links
    urlcolor=blue           % color of external links
}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2206}{\(\Delta\)}
\begin{document}

\newpage

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{references.bib}

\appendix
\section{Appendix}\label{appendix}

\setcounter{table}{0}
\renewcommand\thefigure{\thesection\arabic{figure}}    
\renewcommand{\thetable}{A\arabic{table}}
```

Comment: Please make your code complete. The end is missing. And it seems to me that a lot of the code isn't necessary for this example.

Comment: dear  @PietervanOostrum thanks a lot! I copied the packages loaded in my actual document as I have a big one. Would it mean I have to copy 8 tables to the appendix to showcase the error?

Comment: if the outputted text of a reference is wrong, you have the \label in the wrong place. If the link is wrong then the `\theHtable` value is not unique, do something like `\renewcommand{\theHtable}{A\arabic{table}}` for the appendix.